# How to limit stdout.log file size when running Apache Tomcat as Windows service?

Tags: tomcat, logging, windows-services, stdout

Is there any way that I could limit the size of the `stdout.log` file in Apache Tomcat? When running as a service `system.out` statements go to the stdout file. But I need to have a mechanism where I can control the size of the stdout log file by creating new files after reaching 2GB size or something like that. As of now a new file is created everyday but that is not sufficient.

Comment: Attlassian-Support tackled this. And the answer basically was: "Nope, you can't log rotate this file and that's by design. So work around it!" https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-rotate-the-tomcat-catalina-log-file-on-windows-852592789.html (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/m4aDP).)

Comment: Is it still No for Latest tomcat versions  @StackzOfZtuff ?

Answer (score 12):

In Windows you can go to go to `Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin` and run `tomcat6w.exe` as administrator
Under the Java tab, in the Java Options section add the following:
    `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000`

This will set the default `stdout.log` file to `25MBs` before it rotates to a new log file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Does not work. Ignored by Apache Tomcat procrun. (Tried on one of my old servers: Procrun `1.0.15.0 64-bit` starting `Apache Tomcat/7.0.63` with JVM `1.8.0_161-b12` on `Windows Server 2012 R2`.)

Comment: How about in tomcat 9 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted the limit to be 10 megs, you'd use the following conventions

With log4j:

```
 -Dlog4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
```

With JUL:

```
 -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

Comment: Good answer, more informations and examples here if needed :http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Comment: Its not working....could you please specify where I should have these commands...My logging properties file does not have any place where I can change/configure stdout.log

Comment: In their .properties files, or on the command line using the -D<key>=<value> notation.

Comment: Any updates for latest tomcat version ? I use Tomcat 9

Comment: have you found the configuration for tomcat 9 ?