# How to rotate tomcat stdout log file and stderr log file based on Size limit

Tags: java, tomcat, web

Does anybody have idea about below case.
How can I make tomcat logs rotate based on the size and time stamp? I have tried all scenarios by changing `logging.properties` file under tomcat/conf but I didn't get any luck.

In the web application we used lots of `System.out.println` statements to print the log in a log file `tomcat6-stdout`, which makes it huge.

How to make rotate `stdout` and `stderr` files based on the size and timestamp (per day)?

Environment: Tomcat server 6.0.44, Windows XP. Immediate response really appreciable.

Comment: Justs to be sure I've understood well. With "logging" in your application you mean calls to System.out.println?

Comment: Hi venu, problem is that  in web application we are using lot of system.out.println staments, these statements are printing in stdout file and its increasing the size again we need to restart the server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting stdout.log file size when running apache tomcat windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070794/limiting-stdout-log-file-size-when-running-apache-tomcat-windows-service)

Comment: @f_puras, I tried this way also -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=1024 but not rotating the log files

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Andy, No. Do you have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Limit the filesize: `Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000`

More info can be found here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: Astrogat,  I tried this way also -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=1024 but not rotating the log files